# how can give some properties to an element if a button is focused

Tags: html, css

if we have this structure, how can hide the #div if the button is focused

before I used to do it using the selector ~ like that
but now it didn't work out

```css
    button:focused ~ #div{
       display: none;
    }
```

```html
<div id="div">This is a normal div</div>
  <div class="container">
      <button type="button" class="button">Click me</button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
button:focus + #div{
display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <button type="button" class="button">Click me</button>
    <div id="div">This is a normal div</div>
</div>
```

Check this out

Comment: this is working only if the div is beside the button, what about if the div is beside the container of the div, like the code shown in the example above?